# What is the proper syntax to add a icon fonts in HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, icon-fonts

Bootstrap and FontAwesome write it this way :

```
<i class="fa fa-fort-awesome"></i>
```

It seems to me that this should be preferred :

```
<span class="fa fa-fort-awesome" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

since the span element is not semantic (unlike the i tag), and the aria-hidden attribute makes the element ignored by screen readers.

But could this be this overkill, and should I just go with their syntax ?

Comment: I use FontAwesome syntax and I've never had any problems but it works both ways so I guess its up to your preference.

Comment: IMO the answer should be "don't use icon fonts". I don't really like them at all (I prefer svg personally and as a user, I usually disable downloaded fonts and then the icons don't work either) and I really hate them being an `<i>` tag.

Comment: What do  you mean by "proper"? Is there a specific thing you're trying to accomplish with your mark up? As is, your question sounds like you're just asking for opinions.

Comment: Semantics vs. brevity are the main reasons for doing one over the other.

Comment: @BSMP you're right, it's unclear, the real question here is more : why do they use a semantic element instead of a non-semantic one ? Is it just for brevity, or does it just doesn't matter, since the element is empty and not very important in term of structure, anyway.
Also, why don't they use aria-hidden ? Also because the element is empty ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: just go with their syntax.

FontAwesome explicitly states that it has support for screen readers on [its home page](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), and Bootstrap mentions support in [several](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes) [places](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) in its documentation.

That being said, if you want better control over how it works with a screen reader, you can make your own `<span>`, and test it with a screen reader (assuming you have access to that software and/or hardware), but you'll probably get the same result.